How do I keep my icons from being cut off?
I am trying to put custom png icons in my tab navigator but they are being clipped off. This is not an issue for my inactive icons but it is for my active icons that have more width. I have tried putting them in a View but nothing seems to help.
I have tried putting them in a View and changing the width to full but nothing seems to help.

import React from 'react';
import CardScreen from './authenticated/CardScreen';
import HomeScreen from './authenticated/HomeScreen';
import MoreScreen from './authenticated/MoreScreen';
import RewardsScreen from './authenticated/RewardsScreen';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { Image, View } from 'react-native';
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
const Authenticated = () => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
        tabBarIcon: ({ focused, size }) => {
          let iconName;
          if (route.name === 'Home') {
            iconName = focused
              ? require('../../assets/home-icon-active.png')
              : require('../../assets/home-icon-inactive.png');
          } else if (route.name === 'Rewards') {
            iconName = focused
              ? require('../../assets/rewards-icon-active.png')
              : require('../../assets/rewards-icon-inactive.png');
          } else if (route.name === 'Card') {
            iconName = focused
              ? require('../../assets/card-icon-active.png')
              : require('../../assets/card-icon-inactive.png');
          } else if (route.name === 'More') {
            iconName = focused
              ? require('../../assets/more-icon-active.png')
              : require('../../assets/more-icon-inactive.png');
          }
          return (
            <View style={styles.icon}>
              <Image source={iconName} style={{ width: size, height: size }} />
            </View>
          );
        },
        tabBarLabelPosition: 'beside-icon',
        tabBarStyle: {
          backgroundColor: '#000000',
        },
        tabBarActiveTintColor: '#CBFF3D',
        tabBarInactiveTintColor: '#FFFFFF',
        tabBarShowLabel: false,
      })}
    >
      <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Rewards" component={RewardsScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Card" component={CardScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="More" component={MoreScreen} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  icon: {
    flex: 1,
    width:100,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
export default Authenticated;



Use something else than the default size in Image style. Below width is set to 50 while height is the default.
<Tab.Navigator
  screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
    tabBarIcon: ({ focused, size }) => {
      let iconName;
...
      return (
        <View style={styles.icon}>
          <Image source={iconName} style={{ width: 50, height: size }} />
        </View>
      );
    },
...
  })}
>
...
</Tab.Navigator>

